# Can't add Firebase to LibGDX project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, libgdx

I was trying to add Realtime Database to my LibGDX project through the Android Studio Assistant, but it gives errors on the gradle file on the second step "Add the Realtime Database to your app". It says "Dependencies set up correctly" but then it don't compile, just say "sync failed" with "Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'"

android > build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
}
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'


    }
}
```

(Those are only the script parts that were changed)

Comment: Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143740/android-studio-libgdx-gradle-sync-error/51147012#51147012)

Comment: Still I'm using LibGDX with Gradle 4.1

Comment: What you've changed, Have you applied any patch ?

Comment: No, I just updated it in Android Studio and works fine

Comment: Which version of Android Studio currently you're using ?