# Android Studio LibGDX Gradle Sync Error

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

After trying to run the gradle sync I get this error. I'm not sure if this is somehow related to libgdx or is it just a Gradle problem.

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018. For
>   more information see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>
> The minSdk version should not be declared in the android manifest
>   file. You can move the version from the manifest to the defaultConfig
>   in the build.gradle file.
>
> The targetSdk version should not be declared in the android manifest
>   file. You can move the version from the manifest to the defaultConfig
>   in the build.gradle file.

Comment: i found a fix for the 2nd and the 3rd errors. it was really simple i haven't really looked .

Comment: still need a solution for the first error.

Comment: It's not an error. `compile` keyword is now obsolete. You should change every `compile` with `implementation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle 3.4 introduced new [Java Library plugin configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) that allow you to control whether a dependency is published to the compile and runtime classpaths of projects that consume that library.

- `implementation` and `api` can only be used with `Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0` or later version.
- Android plugin 3.0.0 requires Gradle version 4.1 or higher.
- Gradle 4.x is not supported yet in LibGDX, there is an [issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/5177) for the same.

---

**So** currently you can't use `implementation` or `api` with libGDX
so stick with obsoleted api and use `compile`.

Comment: So what should I do so I dont have that warnings?

Comment: replace all your compile with implementation or api depending upon your injection in build.gradle file